# Mixed model r help

Tags: r, mixed-model

I am looking to fit a linear mixed model (LMM) using `lmer` in R. The model I am trying to fit looks like this:

```
newmodel<-lmer((y8_FMI)^0.38~y8_MVPAper + (1|Child_ID))
```

When I run this model the following error is obtained: 'Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations'. I have had a look over questions like this published and I am struggling to come to grips with this error.

I shall provide a background into the data. Concisely, I am looking at how the Moderate to Vigorous Physical activity (Year 8) affects the Fat Mass Index (FMI). I have data at years 8, 9, 12, and 15, and in this model I am looking at the year 8 data. There are 1029 independent rows (participants) that have provided data at the above ages, so of course there is clustering in my data. I am just unsure if my formula is correct or not?

Thanks for your reply. The response is raised to 0.38 as after a boxcar transformation was performed, this was the value given to me so that the data can be fitted by a normal linear model. Are you sure that I don't have clustering? Would it be possible then to fit one model that includes all of the ages?

I have performed the suggested methods, however I am still getting the same error. I have just realised that some of the Child IDs are 161.1 and 161.2 as they are twins - this surely must be a reason, so I will try a few different things. In addition, some of the data is missing, so that could be a problem.

I just thought that I was would post an update - I attempted recoding the IDs, however it still doesn't work, with the same error as before being received. Sure there any alternatives to progress?

Comment: Your DV is year 8 and your IV is year 8, thus, I would assume you only have 1 observation per child during year 8. As such, you don't have clustering and can use OLS regression (assuming assumptions are met). Also, why are you raising the DV to 0.38?

Comment: Please post a `str(data)`

Comment: > str(data)
'data.frame': 1037 obs. of  253 variables:
 $ Child_ID                           : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...

 $ y8_FMI                             : num  3.94 4.5 5.3 3.4 NA 5.58 NA NA 5.4 5.8 ...

 $ y8_MVPAper                         : num  12.44 11.09 14.81 6.99 NA ...

Comment: Hi Robert, I have attached a str(data) of the observations discussed

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know without more access to the data, but I suspect the problem may be with the encoding of the `ChildID` variable

As to transforming your response variable - it is *not* required that the response be normal...it is the residuals that should be tested for normality.

Try:

```
data$newID <- as.factor(data$ChildID)
data$newID <- droplevels(data$newID)
m1 <-lmer(y8_FMI ~ y8_MVPAper + (1|newID))
```